# Cannot get navgrid to show on grid

Tags: jqgrid

So, I am trying to use jqGrid and cannot seem to get the navgrid to display.  I have searched and tried many things, none of which have worked.  I am not sure what is going on.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
        <html>
        <title>User List</title>
        <head>
        <meta charset=UTF-8" />

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../jqgrid/js/themes/lightness/jquery-ui.custom.css"></link>  
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../../jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css"></link> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../shared/base.css"  />

            <script src="../../jqgrid/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../../jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script src="../../jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


        </head>

        <body>

            </div>
             <script type="text/javascript">
             $(function () {
                  $('#userGrid').jqGrid({
                      pager:'#userPager',
                      url: 'getUserListData.php',
                      mtype: 'GET',
                      datatype: 'json',
                      colNames:['Rec Id', 'User Id', 'Name', 'eMail', 'Type'],
                      colModel:[
                                {name:'rec_id', hidden: true },
                                {name:'user_id', width: 100, sortable: true, editable: true, search: true },
                                {name:'user_name', sortable: true, editable: true, search: true },
                                {name:'email_address', editable: true },
                                {name:'user_type', width: 60, sortable: true, editable: true, search: true }],

                      viewrecords: true,
                      width: 630,
                      gridview: true,
                      altRows: true,
                      sortname: 'user_name',
                      sortorder: 'asc',
                      rowNum: 10

                 });
             });
              jQuery("#userGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#userPager',
                    { add: true, edit: true, del: true });

            </script>

            <table id="userGrid"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
            <div id="userPager"></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code calls `navGrid` **out of** the block `$(function () {...});`, which is the origin of your problem. As the result you try to create navigator bar *before* the grid is created.

Th solve the problem you need just move the call of `navGrid` one line before (inside of `$(function () {...});`).

You should consider to use `jsonReader: { id: "rec_id" }` and to remove unneeded hidden column `rec_id`. You don't wrote which version of jqGrid you use.

I would recommend you to move the script inside of `<head>`. Alternatively you can move it **after** `<table id="userGrid"><tr><td></td></tr></table><div id="userPager"></div>` and remove `$(function () {...});` block.